# Use go-git to check if branch has been pushed to remote

Tags: git, go, go-git

Using go-git, is there any way to check if I have made a commit, but have not yet pushed it to a remote?

For instance:

```
$ echo "Hello" > hello.txt
$ git add -A
$ git commit -am "Add hello"
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I know I can use go-git to check `w,_ = repo.Worktree()` and `w.Status()`, but that doesn't seem to give me what I'm after, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed VonC's answer and coded up a solution.

```
func main() {
  dir, err := os.Getwd()
  CheckIfError(err)

  repo, err := git.PlainOpen(dir)
  CheckIfError(err)

  revision := "origin/master"

  revHash, err := repo.ResolveRevision(plumbing.Revision(revision))
  CheckIfError(err)
  revCommit, err := repo.CommitObject(*revHash)

  CheckIfError(err)

  headRef, err := repo.Head()
  CheckIfError(err)
  // ... retrieving the commit object
  headCommit, err := repo.CommitObject(headRef.Hash())
  CheckIfError(err)

  isAncestor, err := headCommit.IsAncestor(revCommit)

  CheckIfError(err)

  fmt.Printf("Is the HEAD an IsAncestor of origin/master? : %v\n",isAncestor)
}
```

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/StevenACoffman/fbfa8be33470c097c068f86bcf4a436b)

Answer (score 2):

That was requested in [`go-git` issue 1161](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/issues/1161) and delivered in [`go-git` v4.12.0](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/releases/tag/v4.12.0), with [PR 1096](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/pull/1096) and [PR 1097](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/pull/1097).

You can use the command **`merge-base`** to check if the common ancestor of `master` and `origin/master` is the same (you have pushed everything) or not (you have local commits that you have not pushed, or the opposite, you are behind `origin/master`)

Comment: Ah thanks! I coded up your answer and it worked great.